# Unified Inbox Not Working

Tags: pantheon-mail, release-odin, odin, bugs, eos6

I have an office365 account & gmail account set up -- I set them up by downloading evolution as a .deb, and then adding my accounts there. It was the only way I could find for it then to autosync with the mail account.

Both accounts show fine, but only the gmail is in the unified inbox. Somehow the office365 account remains not connected to the unified inbox. I do not see a way to fix/edit this.

Is there something I can do differently with the account set up, or is this a bug to hopefully be fixed?

Thanks!